# Test vs. examination vs. assessment

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Note that this is not about tests/exams/assessment in the academic settings. I'm doing translation for a foreign company and looking for a word to describe what they do.

This company takes requests from instutitions such as hospitals. They go to the hospital, conduct "tests" (quoting because I don't know if this is the right word) on things like whether the cleaniness of their labs meets certain standards, and give the hospital a "test" report that details the results of each of the test items.

Now since I'm not a native speaker, I'm not sure whether what they do is called a test, examination, assessment, inspection, or something else.

Comment: The company could call it a number of things—investigation, evaluation, assessment. What does the company call it? Are they making an outside assessment that goes to the hospital or lab, or does it go to a government agency or a regulator?

Comment: @Xanne The thing is they don't know what to call it in English since they don't use English currently. The report goes back to the party requesting the test/assessment/examination, so that they can act upon it.

Comment: Then call it an evaluation or an assessment.

Comment: @Xanne: English native here. If it's to do with cleanliness or operational readiness, "inspection" would probably be a better synonym than "evaluation" -- but it's a close call.

Comment: @PrimeMover I was also wondering about inspection, but that sounds to me like an authority is conducting the inspection, and if certain standards are not meet the party being inspected can get fined or something. Considering that this company is a neutral third party (similar to how software companies hire third-party security companies to do security audits), would you still say inspection is a better choice than evaluation?

Comment: I would call it an inspection - that it's a neutral third party doing it does not change my opinion. My second choice would be evaluation or assessment (I don't really have a preference between those). I would not call it an examination or test, especially not in the specific case of a hospital where those words are already in common use in their medical sense.

Comment: "Inspection" is British English for the act of examining the workplace to assess its fitness to operate. It returns an answer "pass" or "fail". Correctly used, "evaluation" has connotations of assigning a "score" (literally "value") on the result, for example "cleanliness: 49%, efficiency 38%, slogan-chanting: 98%" or whatever. In the industrial context it would be usual to have an "inspection", while if the examination is for political or PR reasons you may indeed get some sort of stupid "evaluation".

Comment: Incidentally, I don't know why this was marked down, because IMO it's a good question.

Comment: An independent contractor working for a client would provide a confidential report assessing or evaluating conditions or readiness and noting weaknesses or deficiencies or even “improvement opportunities.”. Pass or fail would be a poor use of funds.

Comment: @Xanne For each of the evaluated/inspected items, this company usually gives a value (e.g. the number of some particles in 1 liter of air), and also a pass/fail indicating whether this value passes a specific standard. Would you say evaluation or inspection is probably more appropriate in this case?

Comment: @PrimeMover Please also see my previous comment to Xanne (SE doesn't let me tag multiple persons in one comment).

Comment: @Prime Mover I’m thinking Prime Mover has some good points here, so I think I’d go with inspections, especially if you’re working with BrE.

Comment: An inspection isn't limited to a simple "pass" or "fail" result, it can be much more nuanced than that even if summarised as pass/fail. Even if a site did fail inspection there would normally be a report detailing *why* it failed, allowing the site owner or operator to address the problems.

Comment: @nnnnnn No arguing there, but at base it's still just "pass" or "fail". And of course a competent "inspection report" will give details of the topics being inspected and the individual assessment of what the result is. But the point is, it *is* just either "pass" or "fail" or perhaps "red", "amber" and "green".

Comment: "Assessment", "inspection", or "evaluation" might work.